# How to change empty xml tags in a file in unix

Tags: awk, sed, files, perl

I have a XML file in unix server. I want to change a file like :

all the empty tags have to be replaced like below example. This is just an example, file can have any number of empty tags with different names.

```
    <abc/>         
    <xyz>38475938994</xyz>
    <def/>
    to below file
    <abc></abc>
    <xyz>38475938994</xyz>
    <def></def>
```

Comment: *like above example* - You don't have any example **above**

Comment: I have added. File :   <abc/>         
    <xyz>38475938994</xyz>
    <def/>
    to be changed to :
    <abc></abc>
    <xyz>38475938994</xyz>
    <def></def>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed -E 's#<([^/ ]+)/>#<\1></\1>#g' file.xml
```

The output:

```
<abc></abc>         
<xyz>38475938994</xyz>
<def></def>
```

Comment: using sed for xml editing can be quick, but it's also dangerous. `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` could be less fragile. +1, though

Comment: @Sebastian, of course, I know those tools. But in this particular case (with self-closed tags like `<tag/>`) I don't see any workarounds which those tools might give. It would be good if someone have found such ways (Besides, such tags are considered to be valid)